# Coloring of material not working for forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

Im using Chrome 79, And using autodesk forge viewer to color the material of some part of the model with forge viewer version 6.0. But for some reasons i cannot see any coloring in the materials where colors are being added in chrome, while i can see materials with color in the safari browser.
i got warning in the chrome console stating
[image: Chrome 79 console with warning]

Comment: from the error message, it seems like the `MyAwesomeExtension` didn't load... did the .js file for that extension loaded fine?

Comment: yes, it doesn't contain the coloring part in that extension. warning on the bottom of the log with the WebGL is causing the problem. i can't see the warning on the safari as the console on safari doesn't contain these warning

Comment: That warning should not affect the theming color...